# How to return array data from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array data, and after iterating i want get new array with another sructure

This is my source array:

```
let oldArr = [
 {
  "20200714": [
    {      
      "StartDate": "2020-07-14T11:05:31.151687000",   
      "EndDate": "2020-07-14T12:11:59.673687000",                   
    },
    {      
      "StartDate": "2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000",      
      "EndDate": "2020-07-14T14:11:59.673687000",                  
    },
  ],
  "20200715": [
    {         
      "StartDate": "2020-07-15T14:05:31.151687000",        
      "EndDate": "2020-07-15T15:11:59.673687000",                        
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

The output should be like this:

```
      [
        {
          x: '20200714',
          y: [          
            '2020-07-14T11:05:31.151687000',
            '2020-07-14T12:11:59.673687000',       
          ]              
        },
        {
          x: '20200714',
          y: [          
            '2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000',
            '2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000',       
          ]              
        },
        {
          x: '20200715',
          y: [          
            '2020-07-15T14:05:31.151687000',
            '2020-07-15T15:11:59.673687000',       
          ]              
        }           
      ]
```

I'm trying to iterate array via map() something like this, but i dont't know how to do it right

```
let newArr = oldArr.map((key) => {
  return {
    x: key,
    y: [          
      key.StartDate,
      key.EndDate                 
    ]
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine multiple reducers to access the right data:

```js
let oldArr = [
 {
  "20200714": [
    {      
      "StartDate": "2020-07-14T11:05:31.151687000",   
      "EndDate": "2020-07-14T12:11:59.673687000",                   
    },
    {      
      "StartDate": "2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000",      
      "EndDate": "2020-07-14T14:11:59.673687000",                  
    },
  ],
  "20200715": [
    {         
      "StartDate": "2020-07-15T14:05:31.151687000",        
      "EndDate": "2020-07-15T15:11:59.673687000",                        
    }
  ]
 }
]

const newArr = oldArr.reduce((mainAcc, currItem) => [...mainAcc, ...Object.keys(currItem).reduce((acc, currKey) => {
  const vals = currItem[currKey];
  return [
    ...acc,
    vals.map((v) => ({ x: currKey, y: [v.StartDate, v.EndDate] })),
  ];
}, [])], []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: The solution from Luke Storry is easier to read and would only require a little adaptation to make it work for a whole array. 
The solution I posted works with an array as a oldArr and will take every item of the array into account.
You should go and try to implement something based on this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your source is actually an array of one object, so you want to use `Object.entries` to get an array, and then loop over those entries with a nested loop over the internal array of `y` values.

Because of the three nested loops, the code is simpler if you just create an array and push to it in a `forEach`, rather than nesting multiple `reduce`s:

```js
let oldArr = [{
  "20200714": [{
      "StartDate": "2020-07-14T11:05:31.151687000",
      "EndDate": "2020-07-14T12:11:59.673687000",
    },
    {
      "StartDate": "2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000",
      "EndDate": "2020-07-14T14:11:59.673687000",
    },
  ],
  "20200715": [{
    "StartDate": "2020-07-15T14:05:31.151687000",
    "EndDate": "2020-07-15T15:11:59.673687000",
  }]
}]

let newArr = []
oldArr.forEach(outerObject => Object.entries(outerObject)
  .forEach(([key, items]) =>
    items.forEach((item) => newArr.push({
      x: key,
      y: [item.StartDate, item.EndDate]
    }))
  )
)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: why limit to first index ? if it's an array for sure there are other items in it

Comment: Not a "for sure" - I was using the code snippet of the example data - the third nested loop my not be needed.

Comment: if there isn't more than 1 item your 3rd loop won't increase the time complexity right ? But if there is more than 1 item your solution will fail

Comment: It's not about time complexity. You have an input, you want an output. The input might have more entries in the outer array, or it might not - adding another nested reducer to make a messy 3-deep nesting adds unnecessary complexity to the code, it is usually a better idea to Keep It Simple.

However, I have updated the code to have that extra nesting, but to keep it looking simple I've changed to `forEach` instead of `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal `for` loop to iterate over the object keys. It's pretty simple, actually:

```
var obj = [{
    "20200714": [{
            "StartDate": "2020-07-14T11:05:31.151687000",
            "EndDate": "2020-07-14T12:11:59.673687000",
        },
        {
            "StartDate": "2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000",
            "EndDate": "2020-07-14T14:11:59.673687000",
        },
    ],
    "20200715": [{
        "StartDate": "2020-07-15T14:05:31.151687000",
        "EndDate": "2020-07-15T15:11:59.673687000",
    }]
}];

var newObj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var currentKeys = Object.keys(obj[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < currentKeys.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < obj[i][currentKeys[j]].length; k++) {
            newObj.push({
                x: currentKeys[j],
                y: [obj[i][currentKeys[j]][k].StartDate, obj[i][currentKeys[j]][k].EndDate]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`newObj` value:

```
[
  {
    "x": "20200714",
    "y": [
      "2020-07-14T11:05:31.151687000",
      "2020-07-14T12:11:59.673687000"
    ]
  },
  {
    "x": "20200714",
    "y": [
      "2020-07-14T13:05:31.151687000",
      "2020-07-14T14:11:59.673687000"
    ]
  },
  {
    "x": "20200715",
    "y": [
      "2020-07-15T14:05:31.151687000",
      "2020-07-15T15:11:59.673687000"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

i think the problem is because you have an array with a single object inside. So when you use array map you "key" is the position 0 of the array, i think you can do something like that to get the espected result:

```
Object.keys(oldArr).reduce((acc, current) => {
    console.log(acc, current)
    oldArr[current].forEach((objWithDate) => {
        acc.push({
            x: current,
            y: [objWithDate.StartDate, objWithDate.EndDate]
        })
    })
    return acc
}, [])
```

i dont really know your version of node or if this is for the web, but i hope this work for you. have a nice day